# How to check multiple words in a string ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I tried to search few strings in a textview string. I tried to find some emoji symbol letters via regex. I did,

```
NSMutableString *searchedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.postTxtView.text];
NSError* error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(:D|:))" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length])];
for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
{
    NSString* matchText = [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
}
```

But this in not working for `@"(:D|:))`. It's working well with `@"(:D)`. Why and How may I check strings like `:D, :), :(, :*` etc?

Comment: maybe, `@"(:D|:\\))`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may note that in Objective C special regex metacharacters like `.`, `)`, `(`, `[`, `]`, `+`, `?`, `\\`, `$`, `^`, `*`, `{` and `}` must be either escaped with double backslashes or put into a character class `[...]`:

```
NSMutableString *searchedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@":D and :)"];
NSError* error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(:D|:\\))" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length])];
for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
{
    NSString* matchText = [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
}
return 0;
```

Output:

```
2016-02-02 01:47:03.723 prog[2261] match: :D
2016-02-02 01:47:03.723 prog[2261] match: :)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/TCR0Wg)

Comment: When you use regex101.com, make sure you select PCRE syntax, and escape the characters I listed. Then, in Objective-C, you need to just double the backslashes. Another way of writing your current regex is `(:D|:[)])` (or even using non-capturing groups [`(?::(?:D|[)]))`](https://regex101.com/r/aJ7oM9/1)).

Answer (score 2):

`)` is a special character and you need to escape it in your REGEX pattern using backslash.

Correctly escaped REGEX pattern looks like this: `(:D|:\))`. However in Objective-C, `\)` is not enough because backslash itself is a special character escaping other characters. So pattern string must be "double-escaped" with 2 backlashes: escaping special escape character.

So in Objective-C, you must use this pattern: `@"(:D|:\\))"`

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/jB1yL8/1

Comment: it says `unknown escape sequence '\)'`

Comment: Good answer, and cool site. I don't use ReEx often enough to be fluent, so that site will be useful on those rare occasions when I need to. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @codebot I have updated my answer. There was missing escaping for Objective-C string